# Can we create a list of arrays and how?

Tags: tcl

I want to create a list and each element of it is an array, similarly to an array of structs in C language.
Can it be done in TCL and how if it can? thanks very much!

I did some try but it failed...

```
tcl>set si(eid) -1
tcl>set si(core) 0
tcl>set si(time) 0
tcl>lappend si_list "$si"
Error: can't read "si": variable is array
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't create a list of arrays, but you can create a list of dicts which is functionally the same thing (a mapping from keys to values):

```
set mylist [list [dict create a 1 b 2] [dict create a 4 b 5]]
puts [dict get [lindex $mylist 1] a]
```

To do it as arrays you need to use [array get] and [array set] to change the array into a string:

```
set si(eid) -1
set si(core) 0
set si(time) 0
lappend si_list [array get si]
```

And to get it back out

```
array set newsi [lindex $si_list]
puts $newsi(eid)
```

dicts let you work on the {name value} lists directly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a fresh tcl user, having not heard of dict... Is there any special lib need to be included for it?

Comment: No special lib, but you do need to be running tcl8.5 or newer.

Comment: There's a backport to 8.4 IIRC (the `dict` package).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this on versions of Tcl that don't include dict is to use upvar.

To do this, add the names of the array variables to your list:

```
    set si(eid) -1
    set si(core) 0
    set si(time) 0
    lappend si_list "si"
```

Then to get your array back, do this:

```
    upvar #0 [lindex $si_list 0] newsi
    puts $newsi(eid)
```

Comment: I think it may not be appropriate for large list which has a lot of elements since there has to be a name for each elment...But it's ok for small list. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, there has to be a name for each array you create, and you are just putting the name of the array into the list.  How is this different to what you were trying to do in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [::struct::record](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/record.html) package from tcllib for something like that.